# Accessing ViewController class from another class in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm new in iOS development,

I have and "API Helper" Swift class that gets some data as a JSON array. And when the array is ready I want to call a method in my MasterViewController to update the tableView with the data.

I tried to do like that:

```
var facilities : [Facility]? {
        didSet {

            MasterViewController().facilitiesLoaded()
        }
    }
```

And then reload the tableView but without seeing anything.

I think the problem is that I'm creating a new instance of the ViewController, but what I should have is to get access to the current instance of the class.

Any idea, or a better design? Thanks..

Comment: You are creating a new object and invoking a method in it, not calling your existing `MasterViewController`. Maybe a better design would be to either use a callback `block` or use `NSNotifications`.

Comment: Can you please give me a good example in Swift (or a link to) about the callback block, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dcestari,

I did added callback blocks to the API call and handled it in the ViewController and that did the trick

In API caller method:

```
func loadFacilities(completionHandler:(() -> Void!)) {
    // do stuff
    completionHander()
}
```

In the ViewController:

```
func getFacilities() {
        api.loadFacilities({
             // update tableView
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If this "facilities" variable is instance of MasterViewController then do :

```
var facilities : [Facility]? {
didSet {
        self.facilitiesLoaded()
    }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not, I'm trying to set all data sources in one separate and shared class.